# How does quicksort work for an array of all the same elements?

Tags: sorting, quicksort, partitioning

For example an array of size 7 with contains all 3's. 
`<3a, 3b, 3c, 3d, 3e, 3f, 3g>`

The letters are used to distinguish which the "identity" of the 3 for the purposes of demonstration, they are not actually part of the data.

Comment: I understand the letters are added to discuss and show the new sequence, not for real in the data.

Comment: I'd suggest you elaborate on what you mean by "how does it work?" The algorithm is the same.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation.

It is called *stable* if it leaves identical elements in the sequence they are, and *not stable* if they might come back in another sequence.

Of course, you wouldn't see the difference - unless you sort data rows with other data in other columns, and only the sorted column(s) are identical. There it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sort and just about any sort that swaps non-adjacent elements is not stable (you could get lucky and end up with a stable result), meaning the order of identical elements is not preserved.

Merge sort and most sorts that only swap adjacent elements are stable.